# Nesting resources for User Comment on Event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, nested, nested-resources

I am trying to get better with Rails and nesting resources. A User has many Event (and vice versa) through UserEvent join table. I also want a User to Comment on an Event. So far, Event is nested under User in my resources. How would you nest Comment? Would that be nested under Event so there are two successively nested resources under User? How would that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would be my suggested nested approach:

```
resources :users
resources :events do
  resources :comments
end
```

In a many-to-many relationship, it doesn't usually make sense to nest one under the other because neither has a stronger containment relationship.

In your scenario, a user doesn't belong to one event and an event doesn't belong to one user, so having your routes represent it like that doesn't quite model the relationship. Your URLs would look like `/events/1/users/2`. That sort of implies that User 2 only exists in Event 1.

I think it would make sense that your `User` and `Event` are top-level resources. `Comments`, on the other hand, do have some ownership which makes sense to nest. More than likely, a `Comment` will be associated with the `Event` in regards to context. The `User` is simply the person responsible for it. Nesting comments under the user would give you easy URLs to display all the comments for a user, but I'm betting you're more likely to display all the comments for an `Event`. With that in mind, I would suggest nesting `Comments` under `Events`.

This also makes sense if you were to delete the user and `nullify` the `user_id` in the `Comment` model. You could still have a URL for the comment. If you delete the `Event`, the comments likely aren't useful anymore anyway, so you could simply destroy them.

Comment: Just a small addendum, you could modify the `:users` routes to include: `get 'comments', on: :member` to give you a URL to fetch all the comments a user owns.